# How to prevent the recorded video using ffmpeg get corrupt

Tags: 12.04, video, alsa, ffmpeg, streaming

Actually I have an device that record the audio and video. when the recording is started the video file also started to persist into the hard drive.

But if device goes off unfortunately between the recording. The video file get corrupted and gives an error: **This file not contain playable stream**

I am using the `Ubuntu` system and record the video using `ffmpeg`

Any one can help me..!!!

I am using the webcam for recording the video and bluetooth mic for audio using the ffmpeg.
Following are the command that I am using to store the audio and video recording on other device(hard drive):

```
ffmpeg -loglevel warning -y  -i /home/prakash/../../output/2013-10-07T22-39-05/right_cam.mp4 -i /home/prakash/../.. output/2013-10-07T22-39-05/left_cam.mp4 -filter_complex '[1:0] pad=108:28:5:2:black [padvidleft]; [0:0] setpts=PTS+0.8786787543577881/TB [right_cam_pts]; [padvidleft][right_cam_pts] overlay=544:0 [mergedvid] ; [1:2] channelsplit [ll][lr]; [ll][lr] amix [leftmix];
               [1:3] channelsplit [rl][rr]; [rl][rr] amix [rightmix];
               [leftmix][rightmix] amix [cam_all];
               [1:4] channelsplit [btl][btr] ; [btl][btr] amix [btmix] ;
               [btmix][cam_all] join [bt_mixcam]' -f mp4 -crf 20 -r 24 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -map [mergedvid] -map [bt_mixcam] -map 1:2 -map 1:3 -map 1:4 /home/prakash/../../output/combos/combo-2013-10-07T22-39-05_dgrt6546533w471567f880abf287a855c_1088x288.mp4
```

If the recording is started and in the middle we turns off the recording device the recorded video and audio get persisted on hard drive but it is not able to play. When we try to play this recording the vlc gives the error `this files contains no playable stream`

Comment: Did you try to read your file using vlc?

Comment: Yes I tried to read the video using vlc. But in vlc also getting the same error.

Comment: Could you add to your question what exact device you're using (webcam?) and the ffmpeg command please?

Comment: @ Sylvain Pineau.                                                 I have added the ffmpeg command on question that I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another great solution I got. It don't corrupt the audio and video files in any how.
You can use `-f mpegts` instead of `-f mp4` in ffmpeg

Answer (score 3):

You should try a different output container format such as MKV.

Your `-f mp4` seems superfluous (unless this is part of a script where the output name is or part of a variable), but if you wanted to continue using this option the change it to `-f matroska` and give your output the mkv extension instead of mp4.

MP4 requires additional information to be written to the file, but this can only occur after encoding is completed properly. If the encoding does not complete properly then the information may not be present resulting in a non-playable output.